# Rails + ActiveAdmin + page cms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, activeadmin

So I want to play with the active_admin gem. Two basic pieces I need is pages and images. I could setup a system myself, but is there any gems or anything out there that make setting this up easy? Ideally the pages would have ability to have custom slugs, nested pages, custom fields etc. And maybe ability to add images to the pages.

Yes yes maybe I should just go with a system like refinery. But I'm curious if there something lighter out there for what I need.

Comment: Still wondering if there's easy ways to do this.. any ideas? Especially for things like nested pages like refinery has.

Comment: One way you could achieve this is by integrating activeadmin with ckeditor. This doesn't require lots of coding and should work out of the box, except for images uploaded using CKeditor. Additionally you could use a custom controller for serving images and have get an integration with paperclip

Comment: I ended up using TinyMCE, creating a custom image browser thing. And created  custom page setup with custom trailing urls. Maybe I can post it sometime..

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: if you want the "lightweight" way, just go to implement your own CMS.

In my experience, for rails application, rebuilt is much easier and faster than refactoring/reuse, if your requirement is kinda of complex.

Comment: Yeah I ended up just creating one with activeadmin. Just figured page creation and image uploading were such common features there would be more out there on it. I suppose that's what refinery is.. I just don't like some of the ways it's setup.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at active_cms, which is still in active development, but already useful for basic functionality. You can find it here: https://github.com/geisters/active_cms

Comment: The project seems dead: last commit 2012-08-16.